# Populate Data from Node.JS REST api, show in place holders

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest

A bit new to this, so i would be needing some clarity. I want a scenario where I would click a button, it goes to the REST api, initiates a get request from the REST api and populate some fields.
here is a dummy REST api i created in Node.Js

```
https://financeplus.herokuapp.com/api/getaccounts/00343799710
```

When Called it gets this information

```
    {
    "error": false,
    "data": {
        "id": 0,
        "fullname": "Lucas Tarella",
        "address": "144 British Hush Ave",
        "city": "Emory",
        "state": "Georgia",
        "tel": "+1(715)-232-7600",
        "email": "lucas@blackorigins.com",
        "nationalID": "AD87334322",
        "gender": "Male",
        "birth_date": "1989-05-10",
        "ccy": "USD",
        "bal": 950000,
        "accNum": "00343799710",
        "created_at": "2021-11-03T11:39:07.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-04T06:38:38.000Z"
    },
    "message": "users List."
}
```

Now i want it to populate the page with this information, thereby replacing the `mmmmm` with the respective data such as fullname, city, telephone , address, balance on the react component which looks thus

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Balance = () => {
    const[accNum, setAccNum] = useState('');
    const[accDetails, setAccDetails] = useState('');



    function getAccountBal(){
        fetch('https://financeplus.herokuapp.com/api/getaccounts/'+accNum,{
            method : 'GET',
            mode : 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
            setAccDetails(responseJson.data)
        })
    }   

    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" width="98%">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td className="homeFormTable">
                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <img border="0" src="images/FinancePlus_color_colorLogo.png" width="157" height="36" /></td>
                                <td width="136">
                                    <p align="center" />
                                    <li className="Logout"><Link to="/openaccount" className="ForLogout">Logout</Link></li>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <div className="upMenuTable">
                    <div className="nav-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/homepage">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/openaccount">Account Opening</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/balance">Account Balance</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/transfers">Transfers</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/cashmgt">Deposit/Withdrawals</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="SideNav">
                    <div className="sideNav-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/homepage">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/openaccount">Account Opening</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/balance">Account Balance</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/transfers">Transfers</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/cashmgt">Deposit/Withdrawals</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="playTable">
                    <table>
                        <div align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p align="right" />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">
                                        Account Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </font>
                                    <input type="text" name="T1" size="59" onChange ={(e) =>setAccNum(e.target.value)} className="searchBoxAcc" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="121">
                                    <p align="right" />
                                    <input onClick={getAccountBal} type="submit" value="Search" name="B1" className="searchBoxBtn" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div align="center" className="infoArea">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Full Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp; mmmm</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="21%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Address&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td>
                                <td width="24%" align="left" rowspan="2">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; mmmmm</font><p />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp; mmmmm</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Telephone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp; mmmm</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="21%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Balance&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td>
                                <td width="24%" align="left" rowspan="2">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; mmmmm</font><p />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div className="Footer">
                    <table className="footerTable">
                        <p className="reserved"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &copy; Finance Plus 2021</p>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Balance;
```

I am new to this, So I need Clarity of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the request give you an answer you have the information in your `accDetails` variable. You just need to print it where you want using {}...
for example {accDetails.fullname}